# Twitter Premium API - webhook does not receive activity

Tags: php, twitter, webhooks

I have a problem with receiving notifications to my registered webhook. I've create an app, Premium API Activity paid access (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/account-activity-api/overview) and now I want to create a bot that will gonna listen my client's profile, save all activities like new comments, mentions and direct messages.

So I've created a simple app in PHP and followed official guide: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/account-activity-api/guides/getting-started-with-webhooks

This app is going to consume Account Activity events on behalf of multiple users so each user must authenticate with that app to grant permission. I've made all of it but the problem is that my webhook receiving only notifications about direct messages. Nothing else is coming from Twitter and I've run out of ideas what can be wrong with this.

To sum up:

- I have an app registered in Twitter with "Read, Write, and Direct Messages" permissions.
- I have an access to Account Activity API (paid version)
- I've managed to register my webhook to an App and it passed crc verification
- I've created a testing account on Twitter and connected that account to my APP with all permissions granted
- webhook it seems to be working because it's receiving Direct Messages notifications but nothing else...